# Can a full node measure bandwidth to and from its peers?

Tags: api, network

For example, can I run a full node, connect to some 8 peers, and measure my uplink and downlink bandwidth to each of my peers?

Answer (score 0):

You can to a limited degree with custom software, but ultimately the data you would get is noisy and not particularly useful. A number of years ago I was crawling the Bitcoin network to get estimations of the speeds that nodes could attain by connecting, downloading a known quantity of blocks, and measuring the time it took. This makes assumptions about the nodes you are connecting to being otherwise idle, and therefor only gives you a lower bound of what their line speed might be. It isn’t an intended function of the network in any case.

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't an intended function of the network"?

Comment: There’s not specific tools or interfaces for doing it, I was just doing something intentionally bandwidth intensive be measuring the peak throughout.